# How does http://un****-us.com/ work?

Tags: dns, proxy

There is this site un****-us.com which supposedly allows you to bypass ISP rules such as content restriction on a particular area. Now , it is well known that routing your traffic through a web proxy yields the same result. But, here this site uses DNS server to unblock you. I do not understand how that is possible. How can having a different DNS server exhibit the same behavior of that of a proxy IP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some [very short sighted content-filtering systems](http://www.opendns.com/web-filtering/) rely upon DNS.   The advantage is that its very cheap to build such a content-filtering service,  and consumers are ignorant to the benefit of such a system.

Clearly this is easy to bypass,  8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are both DNS servers that will provide a uncensored resolution.

Comment: I assume they are google's DNS servers ? This is interesting. This would also mean that the site I've mentioned does not "do anything" right ? since I can always change my DNS to 8.8.8.8. 

But how do you say that it is very cheap when compared to say, checking the IP address for geographic location ?

p.s. I dont have enough Reps, could you please flag the below comment by user12102

Comment: @user12102  yeah I'll flag that post,  no problem.  Yeah those are Google's DNS server.  Its cheap to impalement a DNS blacklist,  by just modifying BIND's configs,  you don't even have to write any software for this.  Having a proxy server and then forcing people to use this proxy server is complex to install and more difficult to write.

Comment: @Rook "Cheap to impalement a DNS blacklist"?  You're going to run it through with a halberd, or something?  ;-)

Comment: Any ISP can break the Google Public DNS workaround by 1. transparently MITMing those IP addresses and 2. instructing tech support to disclaim DNSSEC support entirely.